# Hide a button depending upon the current page being viewed

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I dont know if I am logically correct,but i have a situation where i have set of web pages sharing same 'Header' and 'Footer' section.When user is on 'Home page' he can click on 'Gear' icon present on 'Header' section to go to "Settings" page. Once user navigates to "Settings" page I want to hide this 'Gear' button as user is already on the 'Settings' page. As I am having Common 'Header' and 'Footer' sections,I am unclear about how to achieve this? can anybody give a hint for achieving the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign ids and classes to all the buttons you wish to show or hide.Then on each page, you could use Jquery to hide the buttons.
For example,

$("#button2").hide()

Answer (score 0):

i can help you logically....window.location will give you the current page using javascript and assuming that icon have specific id, match the location with the page address where you want to hide, if both matches hide the icon using CSS or DOM else make it visible.

ok..didnt see you wanted for JQuery..there are some simple functions available...

Comment: hey this might work.. thanx i'll search for jquery functions that will help me achieve this